# Pipe Multiple Strings in Sh Script

Tags: sh, stdin

Trying to pipe multiple strings into a file similar to the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "First name: ";
read ANSWER1;
echo "Last name: ";
read ANSWER2;
echo $ANSWER1 ANSWER2;
```

Wanting to be able to pipe in values like or similar (I don't want to be updating the sh script) and get the following result:

```
$ echo "Bugs"; echo "Bunny" | scriptName
Bugs Bunny
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiline input, use a heredoc instead of multiple `echo`s:

```
cat << EOF | scriptName
Bugs
Bunny
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a command group:

```
{ echo "Bugs"; echo "Bunny"; } | scriptName
```

Each command inside the `{ ... }` inherits its standard output from the brace group, whose output is the pipe.